# Cypress test timeouts when using promises

Tags: cypress

This is my test:

```js
const getUrl = async () => {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cy.url().then((url) => {
      resolve(url);
    });
  });
};

const getUrlAndCount = async (previousCount) => {
  const data = {
    url: await getUrl(),
  };
  return data;
};

describe('Search Page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.config('baseUrl'));
  });

  it('loads every property page', async () => {
    const stateData = [await getUrlAndCount()];
    cy.visit(Cypress.config('baseUrl') + '/property-for-rent');
    stateData.push(await getUrlAndCount());
  });
});
```

When I run it through `cypress open` it works with Chrome 97.

When I run it from the command line with `--browser chrome` it shows the same version - 97, but it times out and fails

> **CypressError:** Cypress command timeout of 4000ms exceeded.

Even if using `--headed`.

Seeing that lots of things require callbacks to get the result, I opted for using promises.

Answer (score 4):

The async functions are not needed, just make sure when you push to `stateData` or read/test `stateData` you do so on the queue (see last test is wrapped in `cy.then()`).

Also, you use of `Cypress.config('baseUrl')` is contra to Cypress' best practice. I updated those as well.

```js
describe('Search Page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/');      // uses config baseUrl more efficently
  });

  it('loads every property page', async () => {
    const stateData = [];
    cy.url().then(url => stateData.push(url))

    cy.visit('/property-for-rent');          // uses config baseUrl automatically
    cy.url().then(url => stateData.push(url))

    cy.then(() => {
      cy.wrap(stateData).should('have.length', 2)   // passes
    })
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cypress run` command is running slow than `cypress open`, try to increase your wait time (average is 20 seconds)

you can do that by adding this to your cypress.json file

```js
"defaultCommandTimeout": 20000,
"requestTimeout": 20000,
"retries": {
  "runMode": 2,
  "openMode": 0
},
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress is generally not happy with async/await, see this [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1417) and the long discussion inside it.

To reduce the number of callback you may try either [cypress-promise](https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-promise) or [cypress-thenify](https://github.com/mbolotov/cypress-thenify) libraries. However, each of them has it's own limitations.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out `cypress-thenify`, because with `cypress-promise` it was failing as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are different way to do it:

**Method 1:**

Use it in Command.

```
cypress run --config pageLoadTimeout=30000
```

**Method 2:**

Add it in `cypress.json` file.

```
"defaultCommandTimeout": 30000,
"requestTimeout": 30000,
```